# Are there any health hazards related to raw veganism?

Tags: nutrition, vegetarianism, proteins

I was talking to a friend yesterday about [raw veganism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_veganism) and he expressed his concerns about it because he thinks that raw vegans can't metabolize proteins adequately due to the low temperature they use to cook their food.

I was wondering if there are any health hazards related to raw veganism besides lack of B-12 protein (which as far as I know is something common to all kinds of veganism) and similar stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main hazards associated with raw veganism would be more around food hygiene. Without a kill-step (i.e. cooking to over 75 degrees Celsius) and hygienic food preparation practices there is the potential to be exposed to harmful bacteria, in particular salmonella is associated with bean sprouts and melons.
Wash your veggies, and if you're concerned about nutrition, it's best to talk to your local GP or a nutritionist/dietician.

http://foodsafety.asn.au/fruit-and-vegetables/

Comment: Welcome to Health. Feel free to take the [tour] to see how SE works, and visit the [ask] page if you should have any questions you want to ask here. If you have any questions regarding this site, [meta] is there for you.